# Angular2 lazy loaded event

Tags: angular, events, lazy-loading, router

I am using lazy loading with Angular2 and the [PreloadAllStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/PreloadAllModules-class.html).

I'm just wondering, is there any way to detect when all modules are preloaded and to preform an action when everything is preloaded?

I imagined there would be a router event similar to [NavigationStart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationStart-class.html) for this, such as RouteLoaded, but there is not.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: If you're loading all modules as soon as possible, isn't that *not* lazy loading?

Comment: It is lazy loading, but the core application is loaded first, then the rest of the application. Anyway I do intend to implement a custom preloading strategy, but I need to have an event that will trigger when a module is loaded first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to implement a SelectivePreloadingStrategy and to inject it to the component that needs to detect when a module is lazy loaded. This is described in the guide:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#preloading

**update**
Related Angular issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14036